# SCCM 2007 Advertisment Run Notification Timer

Tags: sccm

where (in the WMI?) is the timer located if the SCCM Client Agent 2007 is about to run a specific mandatory Advertisment?

I would like to shorten the 10 Minutes delay to some seconds with a Script or via a C# command. But not generally. Only if it has to be done urgent.

The message says "This program will begin running in xx minutes xx seconds"

I know that there exist a "ADV_RunNotificationCountdownDuration" in the CCM_SoftwareDistribution under the root\CCM\policy\machine\actualConfig, but this field is empty. And i dont know where the Actual Minutes left are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the 
 [System Center Configuration Manager 2007 Software Development Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22552) ?

Comment: its the same version i got installed. did not find anything in the sdk. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [**IUIResourceMgr::ExecuteProgram Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc145896.aspx)

It should force the client to run the program immediately.

If you want to reduce the duration of the countdown, you can change the **ADV_RunNotificationCountdownDuration** value. Unfortunately it only takes effect after re-running the advertisments. Do take note, the value would revert back to your site settings once a policy refresh occurs.